# pass iterator as value to macro function

Tags: sas

I would like to pass `do` iterator as value - see example below

```
%macro print_to_log(val=);
    %put &val;
%mend print_to_log;

data _null_;
    do i = -15 to 0;
        %print_to_log(val=i);
    end;
run;
```

It  only prints the character `i` to the log.

Comment: Use CALL EXECUTE to call the macro or DOSUBL instead. There's an example in the documentation.

Comment: Thank you @Reeza - definitely a duplicate in concept

Answer (score 0):

Will this work for you, if you use another macro instead of null ds as below?

```
%macro print_to_log(val);
    %put &val;
%mend print_to_log;

%macro loop;
    %do i = -15 %to 0;
        %print_to_log(&i);
    %end;
%mend loop;

%loop;
```